# Is there any way to manage background services of third party applications installed or make them sleep for sometime?

Tags: java, android

I need to developed a service, through which i have to manage other applications, so that unnecessary usage of data/network can be reduced, for optimizing the battery consumption.

In my service, i have checked if network available or not. if not, then disable the WiFi button till network is available, and automatically enable it once network is available.

Code what i have done yet :

```
synchronized (this) {

              ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
              WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                  try {
                    // NetworkStatsManager networkStatsManager = (NetworkStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.NETWORK_STATS_SERVICE);
                      while((connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() != NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                              connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() != NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED )) {
                          if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
                              if (connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() != NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || !connec.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable())    // 1 FOR WIFI, 0 FOR MOBILE DATA
                              {
                                  //Toast.makeText(this, "MyService no wifi.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                  Log.i("myservice", "no wifi");
                                  wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
                              } else {
                                  Log.i("myservice1", "wifi");
                                  //  Toast.makeText(this, "MyService  wifi.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              }
                          } else {
                              Log.i("myservice1", "wifi disable");

                          }
                          this.wait((time * time));
                      }
                      wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
                      Log.i(TAG, "MyService running...");
                      Thread.sleep(1000);
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                      Log.i( "exception", e.getMessage());
                  }
```

Comment: You may need to share what you tried to do the same with code

Comment: @PatelRomil, i am new in android studio, so i don't know much about it, i'll share the code what I have done